# Center excluding reflective room?

Tags: geometry

Imagine a reflective unit circle in the 2d plane. If rather than bouncing the light back from the center, it bounces it at an angle, as if the circular mirror was not perpendicular to the center of the circle. The angle off perpendicular must be less than 45 degrees. What angle is required to never have the beam intersect the center? Is this impossible?

I'm imagining making a reflective art exhibit that is a mostly circular room that excludes the viewer (but the walls are in reality flat mirrors slightly angled to exclude the viewer - although I'm not sure if there's an angle that will work).

Example diagram of reflective mirrors

[image]

Edit:
[This link](https://www.personal.psu.edu/sot2/books/billiardsgeometry.pdf) talks about periodic trajectories on ellipses (chapter 6). But im not sure how to modify the math if it's not (angle in) =(angle out)

Answer (score 1):

After some consideration, the mirror will indeed hide the viewer at the center.

Assume each mirror is the same width as the viewer at the center. Place this flat mirror at a distance equal to the radius of the room. Rotate the mirror until you can't see yourself. Some angle like A=arctan(radius/width)/2 but I haven't checked.

The result, if you tile these person width mirrors at the radius angled at A, is that the beam of light from the viewer will bounce at an additional angle A every bounce -- until it hits the back side of one of the tilted mirrors. That might be a lot of bounces if the radius is large. So it would seem mostly like an infinity room to the viewer with themselves excluded.

I'm not sure how one could improve on this design.